# Web API with Unity IOC - How is my DBContext Dependecy resolved?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I need help understanding Unity and how IOC works.

I have this in my UnityContainer

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

// Register types            
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());            

config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

Then in my Web API controller, I understand that **IService** is injected by Unity because it was a registered type.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private IService _service;

    //-------  Inject dependency - from Unity 'container.RegisterType'
    public MyController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }   

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var test = _service.GetItemById(id);
        return Ok(test);
    }
}
```

My Service Interface

```
public interface IService
    {
        Item GetItemById(int id);
    }
```

My Service Implementation has its own constructor that takes an EntityFramework DBContext object. (EF6)

```
public class Service : IService
    {
        private MyDbContext db;

        // ---  how is this happening!?
        public IService(MyDbContext context)
        {
            // Who is calling this constructor and how is 'context' a newed instance of the DBContext?
            db = context;
        }

        public Item GetItemById(int id)
        {
            // How is this working and db isn't null?
            return db.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EntityId == id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most probably `MyDbContext` has a parameterless constructor. Unity can resolve concrete classes without registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is working is that `MyDbContext` has a parameterless constructor (or it has a constructor that contains parameters that unity can resolve), and because unity by default can resolve concrete types without registration.

Quoting from [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660857%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx):

> When you attempt to resolve a non-mapped concrete class that does not have a matching registration in the container, Unity will create an instance of that class and populate any dependencies.

You also need to understand the concept of auto-wiring.

When the container tries to resolve `MyController`, it detects that it needs to resolve `IService` which is mapped to `Service`. When the container tries to resolve `Service`, it detects that it needs to resolve `MyDbContext`. This process is called auto-wiring and is done recursively until the whole object graph is created.

Comment: That is some crazy black magic there! This was a very clear explanation.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. [Not very good magic in my opinion](http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/08/23/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex-object-graphs/).